# Matlab perfcurve labels formatting?

Tags: matlab, statistics, plot, regression

I want to create a ROC curve in Matlab using the `perfcurve` function (it's for logistic regression similar as illustrated [in this example (bottom of page)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/perfcurve.html)). I have 150 datapoints (binary data), but they are neither positive nor negative classes; they are the number of positive observations within the particular datapoint.

Example (random data to illustrate):

```
datapoint   +ve observations    total observations
1               23                  35
2               27                  41
3               23                  36
4               18                  29
5               19                  39
6               21                  41
7               24                  40
8               29                  36
9               38                  45
10              12                  32
```

The example illustrated [on mathworks (bottom of page)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/perfcurve.html) only demonstrates how to create labels for data rows that correspond either solely to positive or negative classes.

For

```
[X,Y,T,AUC] = perfcurve(labels,scores,posclass)
```

how do I have to format my labels and posclass in order to make the ROC curve plot work?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Lets take the first datapoint. Do you mean that: 1) 23 detected as positive while 35 were positive; 2) 23 detected correctly while there are in total 35; 3) 23 detected as positive while there are in total 35? In the last case there is not enough data.

Comment: Yes, case 3) is what I'm referring to. I discovered an alternative way of tackling the problem using a different method altogether, but I'd still be interested in the resolution (I apologize for the late reply). Assuming that I the amount of data is sufficient, how would I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an ROC curve in Matlab using the `perfcurve` function, you need to have the score for each data point (which you pass to perfcurve using the `scores` argument). The score of a data point is given by your classifier and corresponds to the "probability" [1] that this data point belongs to the positive class (which is defined by the `posclass` argument). Given your data, you don't have enough information to use the `perfcurve` function.

[1] Some classifiers don't return strict probabilities but higher score indicates a higher probability so it's all right. More information in Fawcett, Tom. "An introduction to ROC analysis." Pattern recognition letters 27.8 (2006): 861-874.